# Get path of currently marked file

Tags: shell-script, osx, finder

Im running OS X and I'm wondering if there is a way to get the path of the currently marked file in Finder.

Like, can UNIX determine what file i have clicked on?

Reasons for this would be for example, I could make a service that runs a shell script, so that when I right click a file, I can choose, "Create Symlink" or something similar.

```
ln -s path/to/currently/marked/file path/to/currently/marked/file_symlink
```

And there could be loads of other stuff that you could do with this.

Comment: You might get better answers at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suspect there's something you can do in AppleScript using the `osascript` command.

Comment: While this question is on-topic here, the folks at [apple.se] tend to know the GUI part of OSX better than we do. If you prefer to ask there, please do not repost, but flag your question to request that a moderator migrates it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to get POSIX path of (selection as string)'
```